# How to expose a Node-red server online (keeping the server running at the device)?

Tags: networking, ibm-cloud, node-red

I need to expose a Node-red server running at localhost at the port 1880 to the internet. However, according to the product requirement, it must be done with a "plug and play" feeling, which means, no ddns or further network setup needed. What I actually need is something very similar to ngrok (ngrok would actually do the job, but because of a hardware requirement i.e. it is an IOT device it could not be installed).

The server is a Linux (yocto) already running some HTTP requests that should be done online. Is it possible to mirror the local node-red server to a bluemix (IBM-Cloud) hosted Node-Red instance? How I would do it and from where to start?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try serveo.net.
It’s like ngrok, but you use ssh as the client, so there is no installation needed.
in your case, just run `ssh -R 80:localhost:1880 serveo.net`

Comment: According to serveo.net, "Serveo is temporarily disabled due to phishing. Serveo will return in a few days with a few new restrictions to help dissuade abuse. Thanks for your patience!" However, it was online when I posted this answer.